# Legend not showing up in Matplotlib stacked area plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am creating a stacked line/area plot using [plt.fill_between()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) method of the pyplot, and after trying so many things I am still not able to figure why it is not displaying any legend or labels (even when I provide them in the code). Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

a1_label = 'record a1'
a2_label = 'record a2'

a1 = numpy.linspace(0,100,40)
a2 = numpy.linspace(30,100,40)

x = numpy.arange(0, len(a1), 1)

plt.fill_between(x, 0, a1, facecolor='green')
plt.fill_between(x, a1, a2, facecolor='red')
plt.title('some title')
plt.grid('on')
plt.legend([a1_label, a2_label])
plt.show()
```

Here is the image generated (note that the legend shows empty box instead of labels):
[image: empty legend box at the top]

Help!

Comment: I'm not there? Quite odd. Try also assigning plots into the parameter for the legend. As well as locations.

Comment: no luck! :-/ I tried this thing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `fill_between()` command creates a PolyCollection that is not supported by the `legend()` command.

Therefore you will have to use another matplotlib artist (compatible with `legend()`) as a proxy, without adding it to the axes (so the proxy artist will not be drawn in the main axes) and feed it to the legend function. (see the [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) for more details)

In your case, the code below should fix your problem:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

p1 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="green")
p2 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="red")
legend([p1, p2], [a1_label, a2_label])
```

[image]

Comment: great!! Thanks. :-) This solved my issue. I was also looking into a hack but a different one i.e. plt.text(color='color') at the top-right corner of the plot to handle this exception, but your answer is exactly to the point. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks!. Is there similar way to set labels if we use fill_between?

Comment: I was using Patches before, and for some reason they stopped working (or they worked on Mac, but not Linux?). But this Rectangle/label combo does work, so thanks.

Comment: As of today this answer is outdated, and the code of the OP will show a legend correctly, see e.g. @Fernando Ferreira answer

Answer (score 19):

gcalmettes's answer was a helpful start, but I wanted my legend to pick up the colors that the stackplot had automatically assigned. Here's how I did it:

```
polys = pyplot.stackplot(x, y)
legendProxies = []
for poly in polys:
    legendProxies.append(pyplot.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=poly.get_facecolor()[0]))
```

Answer (score 18):

Another, arguably easier, technique is to plot an empty data set, and use it's legend entry:

```
plt.plot([], [], color='green', linewidth=10)
plt.plot([], [], color='red', linewidth=10)
```

This works well if you have other data labels for the legend, too:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Only to give an update about this matter as I as looking for it. At 2016, PolyCollection already provide support to the label attribute as you can see:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3303#event-182205203