# Plotting stochastic processes in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, scipy

Say I have a stochastic process defined between `[0... N]`, e.g. `N=50`. For every location, I have several samples (e.g. `m=100` samples) (representing my sampling distribution at each location). One way to look at this is as a numpy 2D array of size `(m,N)`.

How can I plot this intuitively in `matplotlib`?

One possibility is to plot the process as a 1D plot along with an **envelope of varying thickness** and shade that captures the density of these distributions, something along the lines of what I show below. How can I do this in `matplotlib`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Histograms might help you?

Comment: Alternatively, this might be a good candidate for [beanplots](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.beanplot.html) or possibly [functional boxplots](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.functional.fboxplot.html) (if each of the `m` samples corresponds to a trace through the process, and they're fairly "similar").

Comment: If you have drawings or diagrams of it, it would be much helpful.

Comment: @dougul - Thanks for the link . It is really cool . I liked your idea of beanplots

Comment: @blueMix I have added a few examples.

Comment: You can make all of those plots in `matplotlib`.  What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first example, you can simply compute the percentiles at each fixed location, and then plot them using `plt.fill_between`.

something like this

```
# Last-modified: 16 Oct 2013 05:08:28 PM
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generating fake data
locations = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
medians   = locations/(1.0+(locations/5.0)**2)
disps     = 0.1+0.5*locations/(1.0+(locations/5.0)**2.)
points    = np.empty([50, 100])
for i in xrange(50) :
    points[i,:] = np.random.normal(loc=medians[i], scale=disps[i], size=100)

# finding percentiles
pcts = np.array([20, 35, 45, 55, 65, 80])
layers = np.empty([50, 6])
for i in xrange(50) : 
    _sorted = np.sort(points[i,:])
    layers[i, :] = _sorted[pcts]

# plot the layers
colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "green", "blue"]
for i in xrange(5) :
    plt.fill_between(locations, layers[:, i], layers[:, i+1], color=colors[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `stackplot` might also make this easier.

Comment: @tcaswell indeed, but for some reason I like the flexibility behind `fill_between` -- I feel better with fewer layers of packaging in utility functions ;-)

Comment: @tcaswell and nye17 - I am having problems adding labels to this plot. I tried passing the argument `label='nth quartile'` to `plt.fill_between` and then calling `pl.legend(loc=4)`, but in contrast to regular plots, no legend appears when using `plt.fill_between`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Josh You need to use proxy artists http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534130/legend-not-showing-up-in-matplotlib-stacked-area-plot/14534830#14534830

Comment: @Josh If you want legends with color blocks, then try @tcaswell's link; otherwise if you want the annotations like the ones in your example plot, jus use `annotate` or `text`.      http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html