# Scatter plot with varying Quantile/Percentile in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, regression, data-visualization

Basically, I want to plot a scatter plot between two variables with varying percentile, I've plotted the scatter plot with the following toy code but I'm unable to plot it for different percentile (quantile).

```
quantiles = [1,10,25,50,50,75,90,99]
grays = ["#DCDCDC", "#A9A9A9", "#2F4F4F","#A9A9A9", "#DCDCDC"]
alpha = 0.3
data = df[['area_log','mr_ecdf']]
y = data['mr_ecdf']
x = data['area_log']
idx   = np.argsort(x)
x = np.array(x)[idx]
y = np.array(y)[idx]
for i in range(len(quantiles)//2):   
    plt.fill_between(x, y, y, color='black', alpha = alpha, label=f"{quantiles[i]}")
    lower_lim = np.percentile(y, quantiles[i])
    upper_lim = np.percentile(y, 100-quantiles[i])
    data = data[data['mr_ecdf'] >= lower_lim]
    data = data[data['mr_ecdf'] <= upper_lim]   
    y = data['mr_ecdf']
    x = data['area_log']
    idx   = np.argsort(x)
    x = np.array(x)[idx]
    y = np.array(y)[idx]
data = df[['area_log','mr_ecdf']]
y = data['mr_ecdf']
x = data['area_log']
plt.scatter(x, y,s=1, color = 'r', label = 'data')
plt.legend()
# axes.set_ylim([0,1])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR6F3.png)
data link : [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Y28_Gkh7w2AQz56vXW2uUOYGvgr8H1z/view?usp=sharing)

I want plot something like this (First- (1,1)):

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib has an example code for this [using `fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py). The strategy would be to calculate and plot first the 1-99% band with a low alpha value, then the 10-90% band with a higher alpha value, ..., I think it is rather clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting stochastic processes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413016/plotting-stochastic-processes-in-python)

Comment: This is *very* different problem than in the suggested duplicate ([Plotting stochastic processes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413016/plotting-stochastic-processes-in-python)) as in the [Plotting stochastic processes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413016/plotting-stochastic-processes-in-python) the x-variable is *discrete* (i.e. categorical). In this case, the x-variable is *continuous*.

Comment: Although this question is a bit old, for any one looking for an answer, the scatter quantiles could be computed with a quantile regression model. I like to use the `GradientBoostingRegressor` from scikit-learn, with `loss="quantile"`.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by @Mr. T, one way to do that is to calculate the CIs yourself and then plot them using [plt.fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py). The data you show pose a problem since there is not enough points and variance so you'll never get what is on your pictures (and the separation in my figure is also not clear so I have put another example below to show how it works). If you have data for that, post it, I will update. Anyway, you should check the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413016/plotting-stochastic-processes-in-python) I mentioned in the comment and some way of doing it follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([5,7,8,7,2,17,2,9,4,11,12,9,6])
y = np.array([99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86])

idx   = np.argsort(x)

x = np.array(x)[idx]
y = np.array(y)[idx]

# Create a list of quantiles to calculate
quantiles = [0.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95]
grays = ["#DCDCDC", "#A9A9A9", "#2F4F4F","#A9A9A9", "#DCDCDC"]

alpha = 0.3

plt.fill_between(x, y-np.percentile(y, 0.5), y+np.percentile(y, 0.5), color=grays[2], alpha = alpha, label="0.50")

# if the percentiles are symmetrical and we want labels on both sides
for i in range(len(quantiles)//2):
    plt.fill_between(x, y, y+np.percentile(y, quantiles[i]), color=grays[i], alpha = alpha, label=f"{quantiles[i]}")
    plt.fill_between(x, y-np.percentile(y, quantiles[-(i+1)]),y, color=grays[-(i+1)], alpha = alpha, label=f"{quantiles[-(i+1)]}")

plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'r', label = 'data')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

EDIT:
Some explanation. I am not sure what is not correct in my code, but I would be happy if you can tell me -- there is always a way for improvement (Thanks to @Mr T. again for the catch). Nevertheless, the fill between function does the following:

> Fill the area between two horizontal curves.
> The curves are defined by the points (x, y1) and (x, y2)

So you specify by the y1 and y2 where you want to have the graph filled with a colour. Let me bring another example:

```py
X = np.linspace(120, 50, 71)
Y = X + 20*np.random.randn(71)
plt.fill_between(X, Y-np.percentile(Y, 95),Y+np.percentile(Y, 95), color="k", alpha = alpha)
plt.fill_between(X, Y-np.percentile(Y, 80),Y+np.percentile(Y, 80), color="r", alpha = alpha)
plt.fill_between(X, Y-np.percentile(Y, 60),Y, color="b", alpha = alpha)
plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'r', label = 'data')
```

[image]

I generated some random data to see what is happening. The line `plt.fill_between(X, Y-np.percentile(Y, 60),Y, color="b", alpha = alpha)` is plotting the fill only from the 60th percentile below `Y` up to `Y`. The other two lines are covering the space always from both sides of `Y` (hence the +-). You can see that the percentiles overlap, of course they do, they must -- a 90 percentile includes the 60 as well. So you see only the differences between them. You could plot the data in the opposite order (or change z-factor) but then all would be covered by the highest percentile. I hope this clarifies the answer. Also, your question is perfectly fine, sorry if my answer feels not neutral. Just if you had also the data for the graphs and not only the picture, my/others answer could be more tailored :).

Comment: I'm extremely sorry; your solution is really helpful, I didn't mean to offend you. can you please explain how is the fill_between working, I tried tweaking and found that it fills every thing with the last percentile, i.e 0.95 in this case, I guess other percentile band is getting overcasted by the highest percentile ? can you please help.

Comment: I did not write this answer; @MyWork did not write the comment you refer to. And it is correct that this answer code is not working properly.

Comment: @MyWork For a start: count the number of bands your plot generates. `print(i, q, quantiles[-i])` may give you a hint what is wrong with your loop. You may also want to try other data like `x = np.random.normal(50, 20, n)` that are not equally distributed along the x-axis.

Comment: @Mr.T, you're right, thanks a lot, my bad. For loop fixed.

Comment: @MyWork Thank you for explaining. Now, I understand the working. But what it does is expand the Y-range, I tried something and have updated in the question with that original data. Kindly, have a look.